# probably an elementary question concerning indexing vr controller data in an aframe framework

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

Starting from the A-frame examples (https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/tree/master/examples/showcase/comicbook), I am currently able to increment and decrement with my quest controllers (left and right) after a quick script change, however they seem to have independent indexes. For example, if on page3 and I right triggerdown, I go to page4. Yet, if I left trigggerdown from the now page4, I should go to page 5, but I still go to page 4 again. If I then right gripdown to go to back page3, I should be able to left triggerdown to go back to page4, but instead I'd go to page5 since the left triggerdown indexed page4 as current.

Here's my page-controls.js file -- only slightly modified from the A-frame example to include gripdown previousPage:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('page-controls', {
  init: function () {
    var self = this;
    var el = this.el;
    var pageEl = this.pageEl = document.querySelector('[layer]');
    pageEl.object3D.position.set(0, 1.8, -2.5);

    this.pageIndex = 0;
    this.pages = [
      {
        page: 'page1',
        color: '#494949'
      },
      {
        page: 'page2',
        color: '#d471aa'
      },
      {
        page: 'page3',
        color: '#794782'
      },
      {
        page: 'page4',
        color: '#7d0147'
      },
      {
        page: 'page5',
        color: '#b06c85'
      }];

    this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.acceleration = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.friction = 2.0;
    this.onThumbstickChanged = this.onThumbstickChanged.bind(this);
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    el.addEventListener('thumbstickmoved', this.onThumbstickChanged);
    el.addEventListener('triggerdown', this.nextPage);
    el.addEventListener('gripdown', this.previousPage);
    document.addEventListener('click', this.nextPage); // Adjust the click behavior if needed
    el.addEventListener('bbuttondown', function () { self.zoomOut = true; });
    el.addEventListener('ybuttondown', function () { self.zoomOut = true; });
    el.addEventListener('bbuttonup', function () { self.zoomOut = false; });
    el.addEventListener('ybuttonup', function () { self.zoomOut = false; });
    el.addEventListener('abuttondown', function () { self.zoomIn = true; });
    el.addEventListener('xbuttondown', function () { self.zoomIn = true; });
    el.addEventListener('abuttonup', function () { self.zoomIn = false; });
    el.addEventListener('xbuttonup', function () { self.zoomIn = false; });
    el.addEventListener('thumbstickdown', function () { pageEl.components.layer.toggleCompositorLayer(); });
    this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('enter-vr', function () { pageEl.object3D.position.set(0, 1.8, -1.5); });
  },

  nextPage: function () {
    this.pageIndex = (this.pageIndex + 1) % this.pages.length;
    this.updatePage();
  },

  previousPage: function () {
    this.pageIndex = (this.pageIndex - 1 + this.pages.length) % this.pages.length;
    this.updatePage();
  },

  updatePage: function () {
    const pageId = this.pages[this.pageIndex].page;
    this.pageEl.setAttribute('layer', 'src', '#' + pageId);
    this.el.sceneEl.setAttribute('background', 'color', this.pages[this.pageIndex].color);
  },

  tick: function (time, delta) {
    var timeDelta = delta / 1000;
    this.updateVelocity(timeDelta);
    this.updatePosition(timeDelta);
    this.zoom(timeDelta);
  },

  updateVelocity: function (delta) {
    this.velocity.x += this.acceleration.x * delta;
    this.velocity.y += this.acceleration.y * delta;

    var scaledEasing = Math.pow(1 / this.friction, delta * 60);
    this.velocity.x = this.velocity.x * scaledEasing;
    this.velocity.y = this.velocity.y * scaledEasing;

    if (Math.abs(this.velocity.x) < 0.0001) { this.velocity.x = 0; }
    if (Math.abs(this.velocity.y) < 0.0001) { this.velocity.y = 0; }
  },

  updatePosition: function (delta) {
    var newX = this.pageEl.object3D.position.x + this.velocity.x * delta;
    var newY = this.pageEl.object3D.position.y + this.velocity.y * delta;

    if (Math.abs(newX) < 1.5) { this.pageEl.object3D.position.x = newX; }
    if (Math.abs(newY) < 2) { this.pageEl.object3D.position.y = newY; }
  },

  onThumbstickChanged: function (evt) {
    this.acceleration.x = evt.detail.x * 80;
    this.acceleration.y = -evt.detail.y * 80;
  },

  zoom: function (delta) {
    var position = this.pageEl.object3D.position;
    if (position.z < -1.0 && this.zoomIn) {
      position.z += 2.5 * delta;
    }

    if (position.z > -1.8 && this.zoomOut) {
      position.z -= 2.5 * delta;
    }
  }
});
```

I was expecting to have the pageIndex store in session memory the current page so that each controller can increment and decrement respectively, end eventually create a 'setPage' (listening to a dropdown menu) function in addition to the nextPage and previousPage functions.

---

To reiterate the issue: If I start on page1 and right triggerdown 3 times, I go to page4. If I left trigger once i SHOULD go to page5, but instead I go to page2.

Comment: each hand has its own `page-controls` component?